# Wrong characters read from a text file

Tags: java

I make a small program to read a file, find a certain string, replace it, and write a new file. Here's my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line;

    try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("a.xml");
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fstream);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(bis);

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("someregex");

        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        while (in.available() != 0) {
            line = in.readLine();

            Matcher matcher = p.matcher(line);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                String filtered = matcher.group();
                int len = filtered.length() - 8;
                String city = filtered.substring(7, len);
                line = line.replaceAll("someregex", city);
                content.append(line).append("\n");
            } else {
                content.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        }

        in.close();

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("b.xml"));
        out.write(content.toString());
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The problem is that file contain some unicode character and Java didn't preserve it. I have this sentence: "Lovely Visit to the Penang’s Eastern & Oriental". Java write it as "Lovely Visit to the Penangâs Eastern & Oriental". How to preserve the unicode character?

Comment: You should read the JavaDoc on DataInputStream.readLine() as to why it is deprecated, it will explain your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use an `InputStreamReader`.  There are a few ways to do this, but here is one: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/stream.html

Their example is:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF8");
```

Edit: As suggested by Joop in the comments, the modern version should be used, so `"UTF-8"`.

Comment: Or "UTF-8", the newer variant. Drop the DataInputStream too.

Comment: This only works if the XML file has been UTF-8 encoded. It's the default for XML files but not a requirement to be valid.

Comment: right.  I was merely demonstrating that `InputStreamReader` supports specifying the encoding.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to handle the text content of a file in a meaningful way you have to specify the encoding of the file. That means that you have to *know* the encoding of the file.

Luckily the XML format is specified in a way that it's always possible to tell the encoding of a (correct) XML file.

So if you use a real XML parser library to handle your XML, this will be done automagically for you.

If you *don't* use a real XML parser, you need to implement [the encoding sniffing](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-guessing) yourself (or just hard-code the encoding if you know that it's always the same).

As a general rule, whenever you want to transform any `byte[]` (including the content of a file!) to a  `String`, you will need to know the correct encoding of the `byte[]`.

Answer (score 1):

> How to Preserve Unicode in Java?
>   The problem is that file contain some unicode character and Java didn't preserve it.

Java uses the Unicode character set. A file can not "include Unicode"; it can include bytes that are an *encoding* of the Unicode character set. Your problem will be because the encoding of your file, and the encoding that you have told Java to use when it reads your file, are not quite the same.

Answer (score 0):

Read the javadoc on the DEPRECATED DataInputStream.readLine() method you are using.  It tells you it is deprecated for this exact reason, and tells you what to do instead.

Answer (score 0):

All Unicode characters can be used in comments, character and string literals in java. Unicode characters can be expressed through Unicode Escape Sequences.

Unicode escape sequences consist of

a backslash '\' (ASCII character 92, hex 0x5c),
a 'u' (ASCII 117, hex 0x75)
optionally one or more additional 'u' characters, and
four hexadecimal digits (the characters '0' through '9' or 'a' through 'f' or 'A' through 'F').
Such sequences represent the UTF-16 encoding of a Unicode character, for example, 'a' is equivalent to '\u0061'. This escape method does not support characters beyond U+FFFF or you have to make use of surrogate pairs.

Unicode escape sequence may appear anywhere in a Java source file including inside identifiers, comments, and string literals. Unicode escapes must be always well formed, even if they appear in comments, else compiler will complain. It is legal to place a well-formed Unicode escape in a comment. Programmers sometimes use Unicode escapes in Javadoc comments to generate special characters in the documentation. [REFER](http://www.javajee.com/unicode-escapes-in-java)